# How to get a scrollable div inside a web app layout

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm having a real struggle with what feels like should be straightforward CSS! Please excuse my eye-sore of a diagram. I've used Tailwind CSS annotation but feel free to respond in standard CSS if preferred.

[wireframe of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTaf8.png)

I'm trying to understand how to make the pink div scrollable without using JavaScript.

Please help!

Things I've tried and issues I've encountered:

1. If using the structure in the screenshot, the blue div grows its height and the whole page becomes scrollable. The issue seems to be that h-full isn't a "fixed" height, so even when you set "overflow-y-auto" or "overflow-y-scroll", it grows the blue div first and therefore the whole screen scrolls, not just the inner pink div.
2. I've tried using flexbox Grow instead of h-full, and the issue remains the same.
3. I've tried using max heights and that doesn't seem to change anything.
4. The only thing that works is using JavaScript on page load and on window resize to calculate the max-height of the pink div through height of screen - height of red div - padding. This feels super inefficient and grows in complexity as the web app grows.
5. I don't want to choose a random fixed height as I don't think this feels very responsive.

Comment: can you pls provide a working example on codepen?  Setting the parent container to 100vh  and  overflow-y: scroll for pink container should work fine

Comment: @ajay thank you for getting back to me. See here: https://codepen.io/SamGreatWaveAI/pen/GRzaQOx

If you remove the comment on the line-items, everything goes a bit off; I just want the pink div to be scrollable, nothing else should change

Answer (score 0):

Please see the codepen example that should fix it.
https://codepen.io/ajaycodepen21/pen/ExrzEjm

You need to set `overflow:hidden` on your outermost container and `overflow-y: scroll` to the scrollable container.

Full code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <style>
    .main {
      
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .pink {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="h-screen bg-black flex flex-col main">
      <div class="h-16 bg-red-500">HEADER</div>
      <div class="bg-blue-500 h-full p-4">
        <div class="bg-pink-500 h-full pink">
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 1</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 2</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 3</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 4</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 5</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 1</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 2</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 3</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 4</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 5</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 1</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 2</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 3</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 4</div>
          <div class="h-16">Line Item 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks again for taking a look. This isn't quite what I'm after though - the Code Pen you've provided has a fixed height of 95vh for the blue div, while I'm looking for the blue div to "fill" the remaining space (using something like flex-grow). 

Also, the padding on the bottom with your solution isn't always consistent.